# Super basic JQuery If function //

Tags: jquery, css, hide

I'm trying to hide a div, based on whether another div has a class.

I can't give the class/classless div an ID -- since everything is sitting on hidden templates that I' can't get to.

Seems like I should be able to say if this div has a class, do xx to this other div.

I'm sure I'm making a super basic syntax mistake, but all the parentheses seem like they're in the right place.

Here's what I've got:

```
if ( $('div').hasClass( '.test-class' ) ) {

 $( ".to-hide" ).css("display", "none");

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HL93f/3/

Embarrassed thanks, as always.

//*Updated*//
Thanks!

Comment: `$('.test-class .to-hide').hide()` if the hiding element is child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('div').hasClass( 'test-class' )//no dots
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HL93f/5/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the dot for the `hasClass()` function

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.` in your class

```
if ( $('div').hasClass( 'test-class' ) )
```